# Opensource packaging software for Mysql Server with Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, mysql, desktop, packaging

I have a Java desktop application which uses mysql database  . Is there any Open source software for packaging or executable wrapper  of Mysql server and Java desktop application into one single Exe/Debian package where i need not separately install Mysql server separately  . Its like one click installer which installs everything and the application is ready to use. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that MySQL is a standalone server, and cannot be easily embedded. You should use an embeddable or serverless database, such as :

- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (see the [SQLite library for Java](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/), containing all the server and the API in one jar)
- [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (see the documentation for [embedded use](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html))
- [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/)

Comment: There are also a few other options for Java such as HSQLBD and Derby.

Comment: I'm an H2 fan: http://www.h2database.com/. More here: http://java-source.net/open-source/database-engines

Answer (score 2):

Just so it's said here, if you are not a Open Source project, what you are trying to do is not only a problem technically but also could be one legally. From the **[mySQL license agreement](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem/)**:

> **For OEMs, ISVs, VARs and Other
>   Distributors of Commercial
>   Applications:**
>
> OEMs, ISVs, VARs and other
>   distributors that combine and
>   distribute commercially licensed
>   software with MySQL software and do
>   not wish to distribute the source code
>   for the commercially licensed software
>   under version 2 of the GNU General
>   Public License (the "GPL") must enter
>   into a commercial license agreement
>   with Sun.

Comment: I am making this application  as Open Source ,Thanks +1 this will remind me when i am making commercial applications in future using Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to script something together and use the NSIS installer builder (which is free) for Windows.

For Debian it'll be just some scripts which have to be packaged together in a .deb.

But I really don't think there is a out of the box, or off the shelf solution for this.

Good luck :)