# Porting Java/Mysql application from Linux to Windows

Tags: java, mysql, windows, ubuntu

I have written an application in Java and used MySQL as the database system. The user can insert or delete the rows in database tables. I have developed the application on Ubuntu 11.10 and it is working properly.

My question is how should I port this application to a Windows machine? Do I need to install MySQL server on that machine? If yes, how to pack all executables into a single .EXE. How do I make this application work on all platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Java applications, unless you did some less ordinary things such as relying on line ending or did JNI, should generally work OOB in all the platforms java is supported. Test and fix the things that don't work.

MySQL installations are different per environment, and yes, you'd need the DB server on that environment too, if you plan to run it locally. Usually, you'd request the user to install MySQL and configure it to your application - I see a potential EULA/TOS issue with packaging MySQL binaries with your own application. If you'd do it anyway, you'd want to use an [installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) to create an install file for you that would include the files and perform steps that are needed.

Edit: see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998430/opensource-packaging-software-for-mysql-server-with-java-desktop-application) for more convenient alternatives than using MySQL with your software and also for a note about the potential license agreement issue.

Comment: You can embed MySQL in your application but you must pay them a fee. You can use Firebird or SQLite for free, both are awesome servers. The advantage of Firebird is  that you can convert your app to multi-user later on very easily.